# Bosun HA and scalability

Tags: monitoring, scalability, high-availability, bosun, scollector

I have a minor bosun setup, and its collecting metrics from numerous services, and we are planning to scale these services on the cloud.
This will mean more data coming into bosun and hence, the load/efficiency/scale of bosun is affected.

I am afraid of losing data, due to network overhead, and in case of failures.

I am looking for any performance benchmark reports for bosun, or any inputs on benchmarking/testing bosun for scale and HA.

Also, any inputs on good practices to be followed to scale bosun will be helpful.

My current thinking is to run numerous bosun binaries as a cluster, backed by a distributed opentsdb setup.
Also, I am thinking is it worthwhile to run some bosun executors as plain 'collectors' of scollector data (with `bosun -n` command), and some to just calculate the alerts.

The problem with this approach is it that same alerts might be triggered from multiple bosun instances (running without option `-n`). Is there a better way to de-duplicate the alerts?

Answer (score 2):

The current best practices are:

1. Use https://godoc.org/bosun.org/cmd/tsdbrelay to forward metrics to opentsdb. This gets the bosun binary out of the "critical path". It should also forward the metrics to bosun for indexing, and can duplicate the metric stream to multiple data centers for DR/Backups.
2. Make sure your hadoop/opentsdb cluster has at least 5 nodes. You can't do live maintenance on a 3 node cluster, and hadoop usually runs on a dozen or more nodes. We use Cloudera Manager to manage the hadoop cluster, and others have recommended Apache Ambari.
3. Use a load balancer like HAProxy to split the /api/put write traffic across multiple instances of tsdbrelay in an active/passive mode. We run one instance on each node (with tsdbrelay forwarding to the local opentsdb instance) and direct all write traffic at a primary write node (with multiple secondary/backup nodes).
4. Split the /api/query traffic across the remaining nodes pointed directly at opentsdb (no need to go thru the relay) in an active/active mode (aka round robin or hash based routing). This improves query performance by balancing them across the non-write nodes.
5. We only run a single bosun instance in each datacenter, with the DR site using the read only flag (any failover would be manual). It really isn't designed for HA yet, but in the future may allow two nodes to share a redis instance and allow active/active or active/passive HA.

By using tsdbrelay to duplicate the metric streams you don't have to deal with opentsdb/hbase replication and instead can setup multiple isolated monitoring systems in each datacenter and duplicate the metrics to whichever sites are appropriate. We have a primary and a DR site, and choose to duplicate all metrics to both data centers. I actually use the DR site daily for Grafana queries since it is closer to where I live.

You can find more details about production setups at http://bosun.org/resources including copies of all of the haproxy/tsdbrelay/etc configuration files we use at Stack Overflow.